# jQuery menu open after page load, should start out closed

Tags: javascript, jquery

My menu starts out open on my page, I need it to start out closed. I've pasted both the jQuery and the HTML with PHP:

```js
// Location drop
var local_config = {
    sensitivity: 2, // number = sensitivity threshold (must be 1 or higher)
    interval: 80, // number = milliseconds for onMouseOver polling interval
    over: doOpen, // function = onMouseOver callback (REQUIRED)
    timeout: 500, // number = milliseconds delay before onMouseOut
    out: doClose // function = onMouseOut callback (REQUIRED)
};
function doOpen() {
    jQuery('#locations_header_wrap').slideDown("fast");
    jQuery(this).addClass('active');
}
function doClose() {
    jQuery('#locations_header_wrap').slideUp("medium");
    jQuery('.header-locations-drop-link').removeClass('active');
}
jQuery('.header-locations-drop-link').hoverIntent(local_config);
```

```php
            <?php $locations = gb_get_locations();
        if ( !empty( $locations ) && !is_wp_error( $locations ) ) : ?>
            <div id="location">
                <div class="header-locations-drop-link gb_ff">
                    <span class="current_location"><?php gb_current_location_extended(); ?></span>

                    <div id="locations_header_wrap" class="clearfix cloak header_color font_small">
                        <?php gb_list_locations(); ?>
                        </div><!-- #locations_header_wrap. -->
                    </div>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: ohh... would you give me a dollar on that?

Comment: i added the code above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<style type="text/css">

#locations_header_wrap{display:none}

</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.hidden').slideUp(1).delay(2000).slideDown('slow');
```

This is just a prototype integrate with your code ..

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vaibviad/wH7YU/127/)**

Comment: I dont understand your answer